# API Client testing tool for capturing requests

Tags: rest, http, https, request, connection

I need a tool which gives me a URL to make a HTTP request that will be recorded and it shows me what body was sent, which headers, which parameters, the method...

It's like something kind of opposite of Postman.

I tried to find such type of tool/service but didn't find any. If someone knows something similar, please let me know, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, Postman has a feature which captures the request:

[image]

Enable it and just make the call to the set port (localhost:5555 by default) and it will be saved under the request history.

[image]